# Is there a way to audit storage in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-managed-disk

I've spent quite some time trying to find a way that I can do a storage audit on our subscription.

Currently we have a mixture of unmanaged disks in storage accounts (premium and standard), managed disks (prem / std) and storage accounts with random blob storage in.

From a costing question, i can use cost management to see how much "storage" is costing us on a monthly basis, but i've recently been asked the question about getting the total size of our storage formatted by type.

e.g. What is the total capacity of storage for:
+ Storage accounts
+ Managed Disks
++ Total storage for Premium managed disks vs standard managed disks

I just can't seem to find anything that will help me collate that data. Has anyone done something similar and can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Are you looking for total capacity or total consumption?

Comment: you'd have to script it, nothing built-in would help you with this

Comment: couldn't you download the usage spreadsheet under Billing and filter the list to storage and remove the transaction/read/write charges and sum the usage?

Comment: I'm looking for total consumption Gaurav

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this? There are thousands of records in our billing and I find it basically impossible to find the "hot spots" of where the majority of the cost is. Even a tool to help optimise the cost would be brilliant.